# How can I rewrite "+ 1" (plus one) to "S" (succ) in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, successor-arithmetics

I have the following Lemma with an incomplete proof:

```
Lemma s_is_plus_one : forall n:nat, S n = n + 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This proof fails with

```
Unable to unify "n + 1" with "S n".
```

It seems like `eq_S` would be the way to prove this, but I can't apply it (it doesn't recognize `n + 1` as `S n`: `Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable y.`). I've also tried `ring`, but it can't find a relation. When I use `rewrite`, it just reduces to the same final goal.

How can I finish this proof?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is related to the way `(+)` is defined. You can access `(+)`'s underlying definition by turning notations off (in CoqIDE that's in `View > Display notations`), seeing that the notation `(+)` corresponds to the function `Nat.add` and then calling `Print Nat.add` which gives you:

```
Nat.add = 
fix add (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
  match n with
  | O => m
  | S p => S (add p m)
  end
```

You can see that `(+)` is defined by matching on its first argument which in `n + 1` is the variable `n`. Because `n` does not start with either `O` or `S` (it's not "constructor-headed"), the `match` cannot reduce. Which means you won't be able to prove the equality just by saying that the two things compute to the same normal form (which is what `reflexivity` claims).

Instead you need to explain to coq why it is the case that for any `n` the equality will hold true. A classic move in the case of a *recursive* function like `Nat.add` is to proceed with a proof by `induction`. And it does indeed do the job here:

```
Lemma s_is_plus_one : forall n:nat, S n = n + 1.
Proof.
intros. induction n.
 - reflexivity.
 - simpl. rewrite <- IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Another thing you can do is notice that `1` on the other hand is constructor-headed which means that the match would fire if only you had `1 + n` rather than `n + 1`. Well, we're in luck because in the standard library someone already has proven that `Nat.add` is commutative so we can just use that:

```
Lemma s_is_plus_one : forall n:nat, S n = n + 1.
Proof.
intros.
rewrite (Nat.add_comm n 1).
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

A last alternative: using `SearchAbout (?n + 1)`, we can find all the theorems talking about the pattern `?n + 1` for some variable `?n` (the question mark is important here). The first result is the really relevant lemma:

```
Nat.add_1_r: forall n : nat, n + 1 = S n
```

Comment: Amazing, I really need to get to know SearchAbout better! Thank you again!

Comment: your first proof does not work. It gets stuck and gives this error: `In environment
n : nat
IHn : n.+1 = n + 1
Unable to unify "n + 1 + 1" with "(n + 1).+1".`

Comment: also, I get that `Nat.add_comm` doesn't exist: `Nat.add_comm not a defined object.`. How do you fix this?

Comment: @CharlieParker I guess Coq's stdlib has changed since I wrote this post. I have however explained my process disabling notations, using Search, etc. so you should hopefully be able to find the new lemma by following a similar approach.

Comment: Regarding the `s_is_plus_one` lemma (the first version): I'm curious as to why the `simpl.` step even works. Isn't the transformation of `S n + 1` to `S (n + 1)` kind of the whole point of the proof? How can we use that property inside the proof?