# Coq: How do I replace terms like "n + 1" with "S n"?

Tags: functional-programming, coq

For using `reflexivity`, I must somehow transform `n + 1` to `(S n)`.

This should be a rather simple transformation, but I don't know how to tell Coq to do it.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rewrite "+ 1" (plus one) to "S" (succ) in Coq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313702/how-can-i-rewrite-1-plus-one-to-s-succ-in-coq)

Comment: `1 + n` is equal to `S n` by  normalization, so if you have a lemma proving commutativity of addition, you can go `n + 1` => `1 + n` => `S n`.

Answer (score 4):

Since they are not equal, just equivalent, you can use `replace (n + 1) with (S n)` which will ask you to prove that fact. Or you can use `rewrite` with the correct lemma from the std lib, which is `add_1_r` iirc.

Comment: How would I prove 0 + (S j) = (S j) then?

Comment: This should be provable directly using `reflexivity`: the definition of `+` is done by recursion on the first argument, so here Coq knows how to simplify `0 + foobar` into `foobar` without rewriting. The issue with your initial question is that you wanted to rewrite `n + 1`, instead of `1 + n`. To prove that `1 + n` is equal to `S n`, you don't have to do anything, it's exactly the definition.